# How to read xml node names using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am new to this area. Please let me know that how can i get or display

**bookstore, book, title, price (DISTINCT Output i needed)**

From the following XML file, how can i read and print **DISTINCT** xml nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>

  <book>
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do with [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var names = xdoc.Descendants() // get all elements from xml
                .Select(e => e.Name.LocalName) // select local name of each element
                .Distinct(); // pick only distinct names
```

For your sample xml output is

```
[
  "bookstore",
  "book",
  "title",
  "price"
]
```

`Descendants()` is same as `XPathSelectElements("//*")`

Comment: @NithinPaul they named differently, so they are not same :) Follow the link and read quick introduction to LINQ for xml. And yes, you need `using System.Xml.Linq` and `using System.Linq` for projection and distinct call.

Comment: @Sergery yes i found it. Thanks its working great. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    public void Load()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    foreach(var unit in doc.Descendants("Unit"))
    {
        string str = string.Format("ID: {0}\r\nName:{0}", unit.Element("id").Value, unit.Element("name").Value);
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
}
```